# Open my own file explorer on StartActivityforResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to get a file from my sdcard and convert it into byte array; for that i used `startActivityforResult()` method which only opened any file explorers installed, none if nothing is installed. so i created a file explorer by using the code [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/). But i'm not able to open it and fetch a file using `startActivityForResult()` like before :( what shall i do? any ideas or examples?

Comment: Option a) Call your File Explorer explicitly with new Intent(this, MyFileExplorer.class)


Option b) Register Your File Explorer for the intent action for choosing a file

Comment: i tried your option a, but i cant return it :(

Comment: for your option b, What category Should i register?

Comment: for option a, make sure your file explorer calls setResult() and finish() after choosing a file.Your code in your calling activity should be working, if it worked with other file explorers. im not to familliar with option b, but it would be probably ACTION_PICK with a URI beginning with file:// .

Comment: option a is good solution mate:) almost done, but how to send uri after selecting the file to onActivityResult method?

Comment: finshed it :) just sent it simply by putExtra/getExtra :P failed to strike:) obviously thanx a lot